# SonarQube Major Issue: Duplicated blocks of code must be removed

Tags: java, sonarqube

Consider the below DTO. In SonarQube scan it says the fields name and age are duplicated in getters and setters. Why is this even an issue? Can someone tell me how to fix this, as I have a ton of DTOs with the same issue?

```
public class Employee {

   String name;
   int age;

   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
   public String getName() {
      return name;
   } 
   public void setAge(int age) {
      this.age= age;
   }
   public int getAge() {
      return age;
   }

}
```

Comment: is the above code correct, it's throwing compile time error first of all, u need to worry about it first i guess, age datatype in setter and getter methods are wrong

Comment: I will edit it ...Age getter and setter is just a typo...

Answer (score 1):

The point is, if you have multiple DTOs that all have the same "name" and "age" property, it would make sense to define a "Person" class with those properties and have Employee extend from that.

In any case, SonarQube issues are just issues.  It certainly does not say "it must be removed".  You are free to interpret the severity of the problem in your own context.  There is no doubt that duplicated code and properties can be a maintenance problem.  If you choose to ignore it, that's up to you.